# unable to read mailgun api events data

Tags: java, jersey, mailgun

Hi i recently used the mailgun api to send the mail. 
i am able to send the mail but i need to know my every mail is send or not.

so i search for mailgun api which gives delivery report. and i found events api.

i read the all the documents but i am not able to get the proper response like they mention in documentation.

my code is working fine but not able to get the response.

here is my code.

```
public static ClientResponse GetLogs() {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api","YOUR_API_KEY"));
    WebResource webResource =client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/events");
    MultivaluedMapImpl queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    queryParams.add("event", "rejected OR failed");
    return webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(ClientResponse.class);
}
```

and i am getting responce as

```
GET https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxcf4a9eb67b97489ab540dcc0e865cb0d.mailgun.org/events?event=delivered returned a response status of 200 OK
```

and it should be like that as per documentaion of mailgun

```
{
  "items": [
  {
  "severity": "temporary",
  "tags": [],
  "envelope": {
    "sender": "me@samples.mailgun.org",
    "transport": ""
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

i search for the solution on net but not able to get the proper solution.

please help out of this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes got the solution actually i was printing the response in console and if print the object in java it call to string method.  and that's why my output was

```
ET https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxcf4a9eb67b97489ab540dcc0e865cb0d.mailgun.org/events?event=delivered returned a response status of 200 OK
```

i should have to read the input stream and should have to parse it into json object.

now i am getting the as expected response from mailgun.

i was aware of using json web service in java that's why i was in trouble.

the code for parsing the responce is....

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    InputStream inputSrem = clientResponse.getEntityInputStream();
    BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputSrem, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

       String inputStr;

       while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
           responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

       jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
```

hope so it will help other also.

Answer (score 1):

It's too much easy to getting JSON response from mailgun `@Rahul` answer is to much lengthy it's just one line code but appreciate your answer.

```
System.out.println("Result -->"+clientResponse.getEntity(String.class));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Result -->{
  "campaign": {
    "bounced_count": 0,
    "clicked_count": 0,
    "complained_count": 0,
    "created_at": "Wed, 12 Oct 2016 11:18:56 GMT",
    "delivered_count": 0,
    "dropped_count": 0,
    "id": "my_campaign_id",
    "name": "Newsletter",
    "opened_count": 0,
    "submitted_count": 0,
    "unsubscribed_count": 0
  },
  "message": "Campaign created"
}
```

Note : When I create campaign that time above JSON return.